How do i add New Windows Context Menu Option with suboptions?
I want to create a new Windows Context Menu option with sub options.
I edited the registry like this: Added a new key named "Option" in Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell and inside the Option key I have subOption1, subOption2 keys, I dont see the subOptions but i see the Option, can anyone tell me what am i missing?
